# SQL syntax error maybe because of the version I use

Tags: mysql, sql

On phpMyAdmin, when I create this table the SQL is executed correctly but when I add all the sql code 
I get an error saying

"`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE`buying`(`CustomerID`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`PurchaseI' at line 14`"

Why is that and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a semicolon `;` after each `CREATE TABLE sometable ( )` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
...
);
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running multiple SQL statements, they need to be ended with a `;` (semi-colon)